# Number of polyhedral covers of a triangulation of $S^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, triangulations

For a given triangulation (combinatorial Type I. or Type II.) of a $2$-sphere, what is the number of unique polygonal covers with $n$ polygons where ($n$ goes from $2$ to $N$)?

Under polygonal cover, I mean, you take a particular triangulations of the sphere with $N$ triangles, then select a few connected triangles and "mark them" as a polygon, then move to the next ones. Obviously, one possibility is having a triangle, plus all the rest, so technically two triangles. The second trivial cover is the other side, where all triangles are marked separately, so we have $n = N.$ But there are exponentially many options (I guess), and I would be interested if they can be enumerated with some close form or not.

Comment: Surely it depends on the triangulation, so what would your variables for the closed form be?

Comment: @PeterTaylor , I'm the one who's asking! Apart from the joke, I would assume, that for every triangulation of N triangles, one could find all the poligonial covers. Or all the possible forests on the triangulation. Is it wrong to assume ?

Comment: Not forests: elements in the poset formed by edge contractions. And yes, for small graphs one can calculate. E.g. of the [simple cubic graphs on 8 vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs) two are non-planar and the others have distributions `[(2, 39), (3, 146), (4, 207), (5, 146), (6, 58), (7, 12), (8, 1)]`, `[(2, 54), (3, 220), (4, 283), (5, 176), (6, 62), (7, 12), (8, 1)]`, `[(2, 63), (3, 268), (4, 345), (5, 202), (6, 66), (7, 12), (8, 1)]`.